# How to detect only yellow objects in an image with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am attempting to detect only yellow objects in a screenshot i've taken and i'm using the following code in Python.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('screenshot.png')

#B, G, R boundaries
yellow = ([0, 200, 200], [60, 255, 255])

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    result= cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 40, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    'do something'
```

It should highlight my detected objects and the background should be black - `len(contours) > 0` if any yellow is detected. However, looking into the mask/output arrays, they are always completely black so `len(contours) = 0`. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please attach a sample image

Comment: Where have you defined "boundaries"? I think you need to replace that with "yellow".

Answer (score 2):

The HSV color space was developed in the 1970s as an alternative to the RGB color space. In some cases, better results are obtained than RGB, especially in image recognition applications.
So you can try converting from BGR to HSV.

```
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100])
upper_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])
```

Comment: Further info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV